# Deleting records which have foreign key to partitioned table on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a partitioned table called datapoint which have child tables like datapoint_s1, datapoint_s2, ...

I have another table called device which has foreign key to datapoint table.

Here is the story;

Datapoint table is about 100GB with all partitioned tables. I truncated datapoint_s2 table. After that, I want to delete devices belongs to datapoints_s2 table. Also, there is no data in other partitioned tables related to devices I want to delete. Although the datapoint_s2 table is empty, COMMIT; is waiting more than one hour to complete process.

Edit: When I cancel the query, this error occured.

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM "public"."datapoint" x WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "device_id" FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

How I can make device deletion process faster in partitioned tables?

Edit:

Parent table description:

```
                                                      Table "public.datapoint"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('datapoint_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 station_id | integer                  |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
 device_id  | integer                  |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
 data       | jsonb                    |           |          |                                       | extended |              |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
Partition key: LIST (station_id)
Indexes:
    "datapoint_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (station_id, device_id, created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "datapoint_device_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES device(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "datapoint_station_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES station(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Partitions: datapoint_s2 FOR VALUES IN (10),
            datapoint_s3 FOR VALUES IN (11),
            ....
```

Child table description:

```
                                                    Table "public.datapoint_s2"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('datapoint_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 station_id | integer                  |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
 device_id  | integer                  |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
 data       | jsonb                    |           |          |                                       | extended |              |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                       | plain    |              |
Partition of: solarify_datapoint FOR VALUES IN (2)
Partition constraint: ((station_id IS NOT NULL) AND (station_id = 2))
Indexes:
    "datapoint_s2_station_id_device_id_created_at_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (station_id, device_id, created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "datapoint_device_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES device(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "datapoint_station_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES station(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?  Are you using declarative partitioning? Only the latest version (PostgreSQL 12, still in beta) supports foreign keys pointing to declarative partitioned tables, so perhaps you're using some homegrown logic to implement foreign keys referencing partitioned table?

Comment: @amitlan I'm using PostgreSQL 11 with declarative partitioning. can it be a choice of dropping foreign keys? partitioned data is kind of sensor data. I look up the table according to devices. Therefore, if I delete device, It does not affect the table consistency.

Comment: PostgreSQL 11 doesn't support foreign keys pointing to a partitioned table (that is, the parent table).  How did you set up the foreign keys exactly?  Are you sure they point from devices table to datapoint partitioned table, not the other way around?

Comment: @amitlan foreign key is from device table to parent datapoint table, not the partitioned tables so I do not create foreign key for each partititoned table. Does it make sense to create foreign keys for each partitioned table? does this way reduce timing problem? Otherwise, as I understand, I should wait for the PostgreSQL 12

Comment: re: "foreign key is from device table to parent datapoint table"

As I said in my earlier comment, I don't understand how you managed to do that, because that's impossible to do with PostgreSQL 11.  Can you add to your question the output of `\d datapoint` (assuming the name of parent partitioned table is 'datapoint') as additional information?

I don't know what to suggest to resolve the problem, because I don't really know what the problem is given that I don't how you've set up the foreign key.  Sorry.

Comment: @amitlan I've added the table descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for doing that.

I think our interpretations of the direction of the foreign key are different.  Per my understanding, the foreign key is *from* 'datapoint' table *to* 'device' table (the latter is the primary key), which is something you can do with PG 11.

Anyway, I'm assuming you were doing the truncate of 'datapoint_s2' and delete from 'device' in different transactions?  Had you committed the truncation transaction?  If you hadn't, then the commit of the deletion transaction would wait until the truncation transaction is still open.